# how to get an unofficial WiFi Shield to work?

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, shields, library

I just bought these two WiFi Shields -> http://www.ebay.de/itm/262525969091?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

As they arrived I put one of them onto my Arduino Uno R3 and tried if my LED test sketch still works. It did.

After that I tried this WiFi tutorial (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ConnectWithWPA) to play around with the WiFi API a little bit. Sadly it prints to the serial monitor *"WiFi shield not present"* which tells me I missed something when setting up the shield.

I just thought the WiFi shield will be already usable without wiring anything. Surely that might be naive somehow, but hey I'm still a noob ;)

Can you guys tell me or simply point out a tutorial where it tells me what wiring I have to do to at least get pass this *"WiFi shield not present"* check?

Then I just realized that I do not have the "real" Arduino WiFi Shield and therefore the origin WiFi lib won't work for me according to this thread: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=371362.0

Sadly I did not received any documenation on how to get this thing to work now. I found A LOT of threads about the "WiFi shield not present" error but none of them solved my specific problem with the shields I bought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere it should say this: It is really really difficult to implement enough of the TCP/IP stack on an Uno to handle talking over the Ethernet.  In other words, the shield is doing almost all the work.  As such, if you don't have any documentation, using this Ethernet shield will be difficult.  That said, it looks like this shield is using an [ESP8266 which IS widely documented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266). And if you search around, can even find people creating [Arduino / ESP8266 software](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino).